# Why am I not able to select a row on my table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am stumped on this one. I am not able to select any of my rows on my table view in iOS. The table view is scrolling just fine. I have programmatically set any properties that could affect this problem.

Here is my code:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

tableView.allowsSelection = true
tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


class MessageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewBody: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Update:

I was able to select a row -- the last row. Then I it no longer would allow me to select any rows again.

This is my entire class, excluding the import statements:

```
class CreateMessagesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewControls: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbarCopyMessage: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var barButtonCopyMessage: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelBody: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewBody: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbarCreateMessage: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var barButtonCreateMessage: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var bottomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase

    var messages = [UTIMessage]()

    // MARK: - View

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: DatabaseNameStrings.recordTypeMessage, predicate: predicate)

        privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {

            records, error in

            if error != nil {

                print(error!.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                for record in records! {

                    let utiMessage = UTIMessage(ckRecord: record)

                    self.messages.append(utiMessage)

                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            }

        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let defaultCenter = NotificationCenter.default

        defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        let defaultCenter = NotificationCenter.default

        defaultCenter.removeObserver(self)

    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func actionDone(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func actionCopyMessage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        guard let indexPathForSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {

            let alertMessage = "You must select a message from the list."

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(actionOK)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return

        }

        let message = messages[indexPathForSelectedRow.row]

        textFieldTitle.text = message.title
        textViewBody.text = message.body

    }

    @IBAction func actionCreateMessage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        guard let messageTitle = textFieldTitle.text else {

            let alertMessage = "You must enter a title for the message."

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(actionOK)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return

        }

        guard let messageBody = textViewBody.text else {

            let alertMessage = "You must enter a message body."

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(actionOK)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return

        }

        let newCKRecordMessage = CKRecord(recordType: DatabaseNameStrings.recordTypeMessage)

        newCKRecordMessage.setObject(messageTitle as CKRecordValue, forKey: DatabaseNameStrings.fieldNameTitle)

        newCKRecordMessage.setObject(messageBody as CKRecordValue, forKey: DatabaseNameStrings.fieldNameBody)

        privateDatabase.save(newCKRecordMessage) {

            record, error in

            if error != nil {

                print("Error saving record:", error!.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                print("Record saved successfully.")

            }

        }

        let newUTIMessage = UTIMessage(ckRecord: newCKRecordMessage)

        messages.append(newUTIMessage)
        let indexPathNewMessage = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPathNewMessage], with: .automatic)

        textFieldTitle.text = nil
        textViewBody.text = nil

        textFieldTitle.resignFirstResponder()
        textViewBody.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    @IBAction func selectRow(_ sender: Any) {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)

    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {

        print("keyboardWillShow(_:)")

        let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        var offset = keyboardSize.height

        if offset > keyboardSize.height {

            offset = keyboardSize.height

        }

        self.bottomLayoutConstraint.isActive = false

        self.bottomLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewControls, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: offset + 4)
        self.bottomLayoutConstraint.isActive = true

        print("\ty: \(self.view.frame.origin.y)")

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification) {

        print("keyboardWillHide(_:)")

        self.bottomLayoutConstraint.isActive = false

        self.bottomLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewControls, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 4)
        self.bottomLayoutConstraint.isActive = true

    }

    @objc func keyboardDidHide(_ sender: Notification) {

        print("keyboardDidHide(_:)")

        textFieldTitle.resignFirstResponder()
        textViewBody.resignFirstResponder()

    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension CreateMessagesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return messages.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell

        let message = messages[indexPath.row]

        cell.labelTitle.text = message.title
        cell.textViewBody.text = message.body

        return cell

    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

extension CreateMessagesViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("didSelectRowAt")

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think you are not able to select any rows? What should happen when you select them?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri It should look like a row is selected. When I trigger code to check for UITableView.indexPathForSelected row, it returns nil.

Comment: After the updated comment, it seems to be like there is a view blocking a part of your table. Are you adding anything to the view after you add the table? Are you using the same `MessageTableViewCell` for all the cells?

Comment: I am using MessageTableViewCell for all my table view cells. I don't know if anything is blocking the table view. The table view is able to scroll.

Comment: Implement the `didSelectRowAt` delegate and check if it is called.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri didSelectRowAt is not being called. I just tried your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, then you need to edit the question with more information like how your tableview is setup, the delegates, etc

Comment: @RakeshaShastri OK.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri OK. I've added all the relevant additional code. I can't think of anything else I need to do to update the question.

Comment: These all look fine. The problem is somewhere else. Please add information relevant to the table in your class. If your class is not big, then preferably all of it.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri OK.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri OK. I've added the entire code for the view controller class except for the import statements.

Comment: When the tableView is displayed, go to your view hierarchy and check if there any view overlapping it. You seem to be having a lot of views. Also, check the properties you have set in your storyboard.

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum, It would be great if you add snap of your cell xib.

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum you have a textView in your table view cells. the textView has a selection of its own for Text as well as scroll view. You can test whether your selection is received by the textview or the cell itself.

Comment: @Hammadzafar I noticed that when I tap on the text view, the row is not selected, but when I tap on the label, the row is selected.

Comment: @Hammadzafar How do I check if the selection is received by the text view?

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum you can override the touchesBegan and touchesEnded in the view to know look into UIResponder for more. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder

Comment: @Hammadzafar Yes. That's it. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum you're welcome. upvote the comment please.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The text view wasn't passing along the touchesBegan event, so I set the class property of the text field to a custom class with the following definition:

```
class TextViewWithTouches: UITextView {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        next?.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        next?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)

        next?.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)

    }

}
```